# How do I make local HTM files communicate, and avoid cross domain communication errors?

Tags: html, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

I have am HTML based manual. It was designed for and works in IE7 and below. It is installed locally on a computer (not web server based, only local), but I need to make changes that conform to changes in rules for Chromium based web browsers. Parts of the book work, but other parts fail. I can not use any scripts/techniques that would alter any standard security settings.

Primary issues are it has links for graphics and tables that launch a "container" html that is supposed to display them. But all that shows up is the blank shell "container" without the content. Console error messages for figures show errors occuring on lines with "document.write" functions being called out and issues with "cross-window communication". I am unclear if the tables are failing for the same reason since no console errors are being displayed. I added " --allow-file-access-from-files --allow-file-access --allow-cross-origin-auth-prompt" to the shortcuts for Chrome/Edge and the figures began displaying correctly, but the tables still failed.

My background is not as a javascript coder, and I have slightly beyond basic html editing skills. The scripts currently inuse were written by a javascript programer before he moved on and I am being instructed to make the transition. Im sure im not explaining something correctly since this is above my head, but if anyone can help on this, it would be greatly appreciated.

the links inuse for figures are:

```
onClick="figureWindow('fig.png', 'fig title')
```

the script in the resources folder:

```
function figureWindow(imgURL, imgName) {
settings = 'resizable=1,width=1010,height=800,left=10,top=35,titlebar=yes'
newName='Fig'+Math.floor(Math.random()*1001);
openwin = window.open('../../../resources/FigWin.htm?loc=' + imgURL + "?doc=" + imgName, newName, settings);}
```

the links inuse for tables are:

```
onClick="javascript:tableWindow('table 1.txt')
```

the script in the resources folder:

```
function tableWindow(tableURL) {
settings = 'resizable=1,width=1010,height=600,left=10,top=115,titlebar=yes'
myname = 'table_' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1001);
openwin = window.open('../../../resources/TableWin.htm?loc=' + tableURL, myname, settings);}
```

(basic breakdown of manual structure)
->Root
-->Manual

```
    ---->Chapter 1 (Folder and Displayed html TOC)
        ------>Tables (folder Inside Chapter 1 folder)
            ------<Table 1  (Txt file with contents)
            ------<Table 2  (Txt file with contents)
            ------<Table 3  (Txt file with contents)
        ----<Page 1 (html page to be displayed and read)
        ----<Page 2 (html page to be displayed and read)
        ----<Page 3 (html page to be displayed and read)

    ---->Figs   (Folder for all graphics to be displayed from Pages)

-->Resources Folder
    ---->CSS
    ---->Scripts
--<Fig Container    (Inside Resources folder, supposed to get graphic filename and text coded on the Page)
--<Table Container  (Inside Resources folder, supposed to get table filename coded on the Page)
```

Comment: Does `../../../resources/TableWin.htm` load inside your container? You must first figure out if it is an issue with the javascript function or if it is an issue of the TableWin. Try changing the code inside `TableWin.htm` into something simple and see if that works

Comment: That is the container html. I tried to remove the scripts from it, but still fails to load.

Comment: But does it load inside your container? I think you may be having issues with your GET parameters (`?loc=...`) so checking if does load but doesn't include the image or whether it does not load at all can point you towards the underlying issue

Comment: <script>$( document ).on( 'click', 'a', function( ev ){function exterm(url) {settings='resizable=1,width=1010,height=600,left=10,top=115,titlebar=yes' myname='exterm_'+Math.floor(Math.random()*1001); openwin=window.open(url,myname,settings);}} );</script>
<div id="techmanual"><script language="javascript">document.title = DisplayTable_old(tableLocation, "title");</script><div id="techInfo"><script language="javascript">document.writeln(DisplayTable(getQuerystring("loc"), "table"));</script><img id="viewSpace" src="images/spacer.gif" /> </div></div>

Comment: that is the code from the container, what tries to call up the info, and where the info is saved. For the Table. with the images, the code works when i use  --allow-file-access-from-files --allow-file-access --allow-cross-origin-auth-prompt on the shortcut. so it seems like there is prob 2 diff issues going on.